# PHP: is_uploaded_file only seems to know how to handle 1 file per restart of application?

Tags: c#, php

In C# I have code that uploads a file Async to a php file, then in the PHP file I assign a unique ID (given by the C# code), then store the file in a database. This can run multiple times BUT it only seems to be working with the very first file that gets uploaded, and not the subsequent.

Maybe (`is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`) only knows how to reference the VERY FIRST file it receives and doesn't know to clear it from memory? So the other files it receives shortly later is called (`is_uploaded_file($FILES['file2']['tmp_name']` or something. Just a shot in the dark.

I'm not going to post a bunch of code because my code is very simple and is not a problem with it as far as I am aware, this is the only reason this error might be happening as far as I know.

EDIT: Fine, its not that simple but here is code:

C#

```
 foreach (MailItem email in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection)
            {
                string email_id = ArchiveEmail(email);

                if (chkBoxSyncEmail.Checked)
                {                                        
                    foreach (Attachment atch in email.Attachments)
                    {                        
                        try
                        {
                            if(AttachmentsBeingSent.Contains(atch.FileName))
                            {
                                //Sending attachment.
                                string filePath = Path.Combine(@"", (email_id + atch.FileName)); //We add the unique email_id to the beginning of the filename, it is always 13 chars long so we can pull the unique id off later with ease.
                                atch.SaveAsFile(filePath); //Save as file
                                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                                await wc.UploadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("https://xxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/upload_attachment.php"), "POST", filePath);                             
                                MessageBox.Show(atch.FileName + " Uploaded successfully");

                                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                                {
                                    File.Delete(filePath);
                                }
                            }                        
                        }
```

PHP

```
<?php
include('../include/xxx.php');



if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{
    global $xxx;

    $uploaddir = 'xxxxxxxx/'; // Relative Upload Location of data file, if its empty it should place in this location.
    $given_email_ID = substr(($_FILES['file']['name']),0,13); //Take first 13 chars off from beginning and that is our email_ID.
    $fileName = substr(($_FILES['file']['name']),13); //This should be our filename and extension intact. Still need to add a unique_ID to this one so it doesn't get overwritten in file system.
    $unique_ID = uniqid();
    $newName = $unique_ID.$fileName;

    $download_loc = ($uploaddir.$NewName);




    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$newName))
    {

        $xxx->query("
         INSERT INTO attachments(
           email_id,
           file_name,
           download_loc) VALUES (
            '" . $given_email_ID . "',
            '" . $newName . "',
            '" . $download_loc . "'
            );
          ");
    }
}
```

QUERY (in PHP)This only gives me one result! I should have at least multiple. Only one thing gets entered in the table back in the other PHP script.

```
<?php
                    $attachments = $xxxx->query("
                        SELECT *
                        FROM attachments
                    ");
                    if($attachments->num_rows > 0) {
                        while ($row = $attachments->fetch_assoc()) {                        
                            echo $row['email_id'].'  ';
                        }
                    }

                    ?>
```

Comment: If your code is "very simple" then there shouldn't be any reason to post "a bunch of code".  You should only include what is _relevant_, but you do need to include that.

Comment: If you are posting More Than One File then `$FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0]` then `$FILES['file']['tmp_name'][1]` in other words you must process the files uploaded in a loop

Comment: Please see my edit,

And so you are saying if I upload 4 files it needs to be $FILES['file4'][tmp_name'][0] and its an array? I am calling the upload method once and waiting for it to finish before doing it again, can I somehow delete the files so it goes back to just $_FILES['file']? I don't think I'm technically sending multiple files at once, code is included now.

Comment: Cop a quick squint at [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: Instead of uploading multiple files at once, can I just clear the array after I am done using it somehow?

Comment: Do I have to make it as a $FILES['userfile[]'] I don't know how to send that type of command via C#, via HTML apparently it is easy.

Comment: So what debugging have you done to conclude "... only knows how to reference the VERY FIRST file it receives and doesn't know to clear it from memory"?  Have you added any output or logging to confirm that you are or aren't getting within your `if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))` condition?  Have you confirmed the values of the various variables that you are setting?  Have you confirmed that you are getting inside your `if (move_uploaded_file(...))` condition?

Comment: Just debug $_FILES, then you'll see how to loop it. you can wrap the whole PHP code in the loop (just the `include` can stay above).

Comment: Good question, I have confirmed that apon reaching the PHP script, everything is EXACTLY how it should be. Then when it gets to the PHP script it only handles 1 file (first one it receives) and ignores the rest, which leads me to believe that it is only working with the very first one it gets sent and it doesn't clear it ($_FILES['file'])  apon receiving a new one.

Comment: There are file-uploaders for many files in PHP, so you're mistaking.

Comment: @PhinFuhr There are multiple places along the way between the start of the script and the `INSERT` where there could be an issue.  You need to pinpoint exactly where it is not doing what you expect.

Comment: @David How long would I loop the php code for? Until $_FILES['file'] is empty?What other potential file-uploaders are there? This is software that could be triggered at multiple points by multiple clients so it will need to handle multi file I guess.

Patrick, setting up the debugging utilities is not going to be very easy, I can CONFIRM that for ONE file being sent in C#, it does exactly what I want it to do, as soon as it sends two files from C# it ignores the second.

I hate to be that guy David but could you write out the loop for me?

Comment: I'd do it with foreach, then you've never take further care about it.

Comment: `foreach($_FILES as $file){ ... }`

Comment: @David that only did it one time again =/

Comment: @David I added in more code that gets called later and queries the table I was putting stuff in.

Comment: Only one item is being inserted into the table in the very first PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

As you're sending the files without any html or form directly by `C#` I verified your `C#` code a bit now and remarked a fault.

You've to see the principal statements I do, about the notation in `C#` I might be wrong as I'm not working with it. So it's possible, that you've to adjust my code.

The important point is: you're sending in each loop only one file.

This is your code, generally adjusted to upload several files if available:

```
foreach (MailItem email in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection)
{
    string email_id = ArchiveEmail(email);

    if (chkBoxSyncEmail.Checked)
    {    
        // collecting attachements
        array attachements;                                    
        foreach (Attachment atch in email.Attachments)
        {            
            if(AttachmentsBeingSent.Contains(atch.FileName))
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(@"", (email_id + atch.FileName)); //We add the unique email_id to the beginning of the filename, it is always 13 chars long so we can pull the unique id off later with ease.
                atch.SaveAsFile(filePath); //Save as file
                attachements[] = filePath;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            // if there are any attachements, do upload
            if(sizeof(attachements))
            {
                //Sending attachments.
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                await wc.UploadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("https://xxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/upload_attachment.php"), "POST", attachements);                             

                ...
            }                        
        }                      
    }
}
```

I removed a few lines with some logic which was prepared to send only one file. If you send multiple files at once, things are working different and you can't handle a feedback for every single file, at least not in the kind like you coded.

Comment: I will keep this in mind, it is currently working as intended, my only concern is if two different clients on the C# code try to upload a file to the same php script if it would ignore one client and only service one client.

Good code edit!

Comment: Thanks! With the new code the files are only collected for each mail - so files of different mails are still separated. Would appreciate vote as answer (green check). ;-)

Comment: And btw. PHP is NOT merging several request like you feared. Each request is there handled separated too.

Answer (score -1):

You've to make two small changes in your code:

- the name in the input-field of the form has to be an array to take several file and it has to be noted / announced that upload of several files is possible:

  ```
  <input type="file" name="attachements[]" multiple="multiple" id="attachements" />
  ```

  The array of files is built when the square brackets are used `[]` after the field-name.

  `multiple` can be noted in several versions, probably it's enough just to use the word inside the html for the input-field without any assignment, the notation I used above comes from the old xml-syntax, you also can leave the assignment empty or use "true" as value.
- The php-code for handling a single file has to be moved into a loop to handle all files. Before changing the form you won't be able to see more than one file in the incoming array `$_FILES`. According to the input-field above all files will be available in the variable `$_FILES['attachements']`.
- Furthermore you've to adjust the form-element perhaps. If you handle the upload by the same site respectively file where the form is located you can just note it like this and leavinng `action` empty:

  ```
  <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  ```

  If you handle the upload on a different site just enter the filename in the action like this:

  ```
  <form action="url/to/file/handle-upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  ```

Here you find an approach to realize it with ajax: [PHP Handling file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979090/php-handling-file-uploads)

[Here you find a video](https://clevertechie.com/php/150/upload-multiple-files-images-in-php) with a solution that is building a few small features around the whole approach.

Here you find the [input-field with type `file`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)) in the html5-standard.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using HTML at all.

My current working theory is that the reason it 'isn't handling more than one file' is actually because in the table I set the email_ID as a primary key, which I believe is overwriting the other ones that have the same exact email_ID, and apparently you can only have one PK per unique record, I am testing out that theory right now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PhinFuhr In any case you've to attach the files to an array-variable like `attachements[]` and not only `attachements`. Interestingly I remarked it just today for the first time even in a URL for setting filters with `?search[]=php&search[]=mysql`, if it would be only used like this: `?search=php&search=mysql` one value would overwrite the other one.

Comment: Honestly I don't know what you mean, David. :(

Comment: It's not about file-upload but just about usage of variables when sending something. Look at this url: `https://codecourse.com/library/all?free=false&page=1&subjects[]=mysql&subjects[]=php&type=` you can visit the site too and change the selection.

Comment: After my 2nd answer I guess you understand ;-)